# .htaccess how can i allow access to pages only through the index.php page

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my folder i have

index.php
user.php
header.php
writer.php
footer.php

i want the user to access index.php only and links to the other .php pages are in index.php

if user enters header.php in address bar he get forbidden error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Remove those files from the Root folder. and place them in a folder not accessible to the user.

index.php stays in the root.

example: `html` is the root folder accessed by `http://example.com`

```
/var/www/html/index.php
```

and the other files go in a seperate directory not accessible through the url.

Example:

```
/var/www/includes/user.php
/var/www/includes/header.php
...
```

you can access those files with the `include` going back one directory. Example

```
index.php
<?php

include '../includes/users.php';

?>
```

This will make your website more secure.